# Присвоение значения пустому полю

Tags: mysql, opencart

Надо обновить в базе поле, но когда я делаю запрос, то мне пишет "затронуто 0 строк", хотя поле с `image` есть, и оно пустое.

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `image`= 'no_image.png' WHERE `image`='';
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте извлечь количество полей при помощи оператора `SELECT` с точно таким же WHERE-условием, чтобы убедиться, что оно срабатывает

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `oc_product` WHERE `image`='';
```

Возможно у вас не пустая строка, а NULL и потребуется запрос вида

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `image`= 'no_image.png' WHERE `image` IS NULL;
```